# Spring Boot Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Assert

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and following some video tutorials to get started. I created a Maven project, added a parent dependency of artifact id `spring-boot-starter-parent`, added dependency for `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-test`. This is the `Application.java`:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Note:**

`src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` packages are empty. This is a Maven Project, I am using STS, performed "Maven -> Update Project..." and cleaned/build the entire project multiple times using STS IDE and I am getting the following error. Also, I tried to create a new project in STS and still I am getting the following error:

I am getting this error when I run this as a `Spring Boot App`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Assert
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.boot.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.Assert
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

**EDIT:**

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.deloitte.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>boot-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>boot-test</name>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my project directory stricture:

[image]

Comment: Tried clean? gradlle or mvn ? ide based clean and re build?

Comment: I am using STS, performed "Maven -> Update Project..." and cleaned/build the entire project multiple times and I am getting the same error. Also, I tried to create a new project in STS and still I am getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: Can you try using `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your Application Class.

Comment: try as Isank suggested

Comment: Also it’s a good practice to keep your configuration/application and controller classes separate.

Comment: I replaced `@EnableAutoConfiguration` with `@SpringBootApplication` in the above code and still I am getting the same error. Please suggest

Comment: @user182944 buddy kindly check my answer and let me know

Comment: Then, please separate your application and controller classes from each other.

Comment: Yes I separated both of them and still the same error.

Comment: Also can you please post your project’s directory structure. If separating classes doesn’t solve the problem.

Comment: done, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to follow software principles while you are learning and making projects. Try to make project in a way that *separation of concern* is always achieved, that will make your code not just easy to understand, but to debug and fix too.

Change your application class like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now make another package **controller** and make class in it for your testing

```
@RestController
//You can add this if you want or remove this class level mapping
@RequestMapping("/testApp")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

For further help. please check [this (official spring.io tutorial)](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4) simple example of Spring Boot App in STS.
And another one is this [very simple and straightforward](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/18/very-basic-web-application-with-spring-mvc-spring-boot-and-eclipse-sts/) to get Spring Boot App up and running.

**Edit**: please add starter test in pom.xml as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same ClassNotFound error. Please suggest.

Comment: please post your pom.xml

Comment: posted above, please help

Comment: where is starter-test?

Comment: Please let me know what more needs to be done, I have updated the pom.xml with `started-test`

Comment: wait, relax, and follow the example given in link. delete this current project, there might be some other issues, sometimes, spring behaves really weird 
http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/18/very-basic-web-application-with-spring-mvc-spring-boot-and-eclipse-sts/

Comment: @user182944 hi there, is your issue resolved? if not then you can simply check my git repo TodoApp, a simple spring boot application. It will help you in finding issue in your current setup.

Comment: This is not really helpful. I have the code already like that and still the error.

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed that issue like this, first I removed my folder .m2 and then I run mvn clean install into my directory spring boot project. that's all!

Comment: Worked for me, why is the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with IntelliJ and a brand new project created from Spring Initializer. Saw this message when trying to compile manually:

```
[ERROR] error reading /Users/mike/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar; zip file is empty
```

Turns out the files downloaded from maven central were corrupt:

```
ls -al /Users/mike/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 mike  staff  0 Jan 16 20:55 
/Users/mike/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar
```

Removing the entire directory and rebuilding forced it to download a new copy of of the missing library:

```
./mvnw compile
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.pom (3.6 kB at 7.6 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar (1.3 MB at 3.6 MB/s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, after I installed STS (before that, everything in Eclipse was going ok). 
I removed the springframework folder that was inside the .m2 folder, then ran 'mvn clean install' in my project directory. After that I encountered an issue with my assertj-core-3.11.1.jar and mockito-core-2.23.0.jar (ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)), so I also removed them and ran "mvn spring-boot:run".

Now it works (but I can't really explain why).